# How to bulid an animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I want to give animation to my menu such as when it appear its size is large and after appearence size reduces a bit, how to go around

Comment: can u please show us some **code**

Comment: i am able to to fade in animation but want to change it to new one, currant animation code is give here                             <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the scale property inside set. something like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <scale android:fromXScale="2.0" android:fromYScale="2.0"
          android:toXScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0" 
          android:duration="700" />
</set>
```